# Why Component is Causing Crashing

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu

I am running slurm (job scheduler) & tensorflow (w/ GPU) running in a docker container. My (hpc) computer has 4 compute nodes. one node is acting strange. It crashes with multiple different errors. Failed memcp cpu->gpu. Killed. crash. freeze. docker error. I swapped out the GPU, nothing. I reinstalled centos 8, nothing. Running crashes at roughly the same time almost like it is overheating (even though I have all sorts of fans and though I have other nodes that have exact same setup).

Just for a bit more background
I had two synchronous RAM cards in the PROPER slot.

I have a feeling that I have a CPU or motherboard? But the CPU does not look burnt or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was that I purchased my RAM from Amazon and it is a counterfeit.